# Options conversion/reversion arbitrage

Tags: options, futures, arbitrage

I'm trading bitcoin option and i'm trying to find arbitrage opportunity with a synthetic short/long and a long/short future position.

The options are europeans style and settled in BTC. The contracts are future inverse contracts.
My equity and PNL are in bitcoin and I want to be hedge at any time so I am protect to change of price agains't USD.

After spotting the ATM call and put to buy/sell, I'm having difficulties to figure out what amount of bitcoin I should long/short to earn money with this arbitrage and keep the value of my portfolio.

So far I understand that there is an arbitrage opportunity if:

> Price of the call - Price of the put - Underlying price = 0

What is the relationship to the amount of BTC to buy to be hedge WITH the call/put prices and quantities ?

Looking forward hearing from you

Thank you !

cryptonerd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Put-Call Parity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Put%E2%80%93call_parity) says that
\begin{align}
C - P = D(F-K)
\end{align}
where $C$ and $P$ are the prices of two options at the same strike, $D$ is the discount factor to expiry (probably very close to $1$ right now...), $K$ is the strike and $F$ is the forward price, which you're trading via futures.

This is a model independent result, if it doesn't hold then you have an arbitrage opportunity (up to factors like trading costs).

If you just trade a single call option with price $C$ and want to hedge the underlying, you need to calculate the option delta, ${\frac {\partial C} {\partial S}}$, which shows the sensitivity of the price to the underlying, and trade $-1$ times that quantity of underlying (or in your case, the forward-delta ${\frac {\partial C} {\partial F}}$ which should be very close in a no-dividend, no-rates world). This will leave you with a delta-neutral portfolio, so for small moves in underlying your PnL will be 0 (if you're long the option, large moves will benefit you as you're long gamma/convexity).

Delta *is* a model-dependent quantity, however, so this will not remove all your risk as we don't have a perfect model for the market. You need to make a choice, the simplest is [Black-Scholes delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black%E2%80%93Scholes_model#The_Greeks) but there are many other choices too...

Comment: Hello StackG! Thanks for the response but it's a bit confusing for me. As my question is first about conversion/reversal arbitrage, do you know what is the formula to know the quantity of BTC to be bought ?

Comment: To form the arbitrage portfolio (ie. using put-call parity) or to delta-hedge a single option?

Comment: I assume i'll have to do both, right ? For an education purpose it'd be good that I understand the 2 concepts separately!

Comment: For the arbitrage, it's 1 unit of the underlying per 1 put and 1 call

Comment: For the delta hedging, it's $-1 * {\frac {\partial C} {\partial F}}$ units of the future (this is between $0$ and $1$) per 1 call (or similarly for the put)

Comment: Hello StackG, my question was not well asked. Your formula does'nt work because the trading asset and delivery settlement is not USD but BTC. I had added more precision to the question here. : https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/57889/option-arbitrage-from-portfolio-value-on-bitcoin-market
Can you take a look please ? I'm very thankfull for your kind consideration